# Loading FlashXML Elite Gallery in Flash Three Times

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I´m trying to use the elite gallery three times on my flash file.

One for Games link, one for apps, and for prototypes.

I´m using the free version, so I´m using URLRequest and Loader classes, to load each elite gallery swf.

I´ve putted the 'Apps' elite gallery into another folder, the 'elite_apps' folder, so I can distinguish.

When I try to run the swf of the elite gallery inside the elite_apps folder, it opens the right images... But when I try to load the swf of the 'elite_apps' folder into the main class, it seems to load the same swf, (or at least the same images and xml settings), of the 'Games' elite gallery swf.
The 'Games' elite gallery swf, is loaded when my site opens, so it´s the first gallery loaded.

To load the 'Apps' elite gallery, (which is inside the 'elite_apps' folder), I need to click on the 'apps_gallery' button link.

Anyone have any tip?

If I open the apps elite gallery on the directory 'elite_apps', it opens the right images, but when the apps elite gallery swf is loaded on the main class of my website, it loads the images of the games elite gallery.
Maybe, I should try to change some xml, because I guess the elite gallery is not loading the 'elite_apps' folder´s 'settings.xml', when I try to load the apps gallery swf.
I guess is loading the same, elite gallery used for 'Games' 'settings.xml'.

What you think?

Thanks.

Comment: have a look in firebug or charles web debugger, you will see what is loading and from where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve sent an email to FlashXML support about it. They said I can only use the gallery swf, if I purchase the coponent.